# Flutter TimePicker show hours in two "rings"

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am working on an app for a while now but I'm stuck working with the TimePicker.
At the moment it is showing one "ring" with marks for all hours, but I'd like it to show two "rings" both with 12 hours on it.

There are two other questions about this topic on stackoverflow, but none answers the question. One is the other way around and the other has no answers.

Here is the current state:
[image: Current state]

This is how it should be:

[image: How it should be]

I searched the web and found out that localizations play some role here. I tried some (the Spanish one sounded to be promising) but it didn't worked. It is also a really strange way to do it over the localizations. Do you have any idea how to solve

The current code is just the normal showTimePicker method:
`

```
time = await showTimePicker(
       context: context,
       initialTime: TimeOfDay.fromDateTime(widget.notify.fireTime),
);
```

`

Comment: A quick investigation led me to believe there is only the top possibility for 24 hour format in flutter. The bottom one with 2 rings must be a native app maybe. I could be wrong though

Comment: ok  thank you, maybe it will be added in the future

Answer (score 1):

[Flutter team (2021)](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/65730#issuecomment-941104186)
In short, it will not be implemented, BUT

[Material Design team (July 2022)](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/1450#issuecomment-1198667022) They decided to use two circles and it is implemented now, but I don't see it in latest stable flutter release.

[I guess here is a thread to monitor current status](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/108598)